# How to set background pattern/image in Indesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign

[image]

For example in this image, there is a grid background in place. If I like to use background for my indesign projects, what would be the methods to accomplish this? (for example in photoshop there is a pattern panel where I can set an element's background to desired pattern/image)

Answer (score 4):

You either have to ...

- Draw the background. There is no "pattern" feature in InDesign whatsoever.
- Or import an image, created in other software, and use that as a background.

Answer (score 0):

Scott's answer kind of sums it up, but if its a square grid you need to use, that can be relatively easy to produce using a table and some basic math:

- create a text box and make it exactly the size of the page (assuming you need full page coverage)
- insert a table into this box and add as many empty rows and columns as you need to make it into a grid
- format the strokes on each cell to a light gray of equal weight
- lock the table object or move it to the master page, so it won't get in the way as you do additional work on the page(s)